# retrieve hovered element from a touchmove

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, mouseevent

I'm facing a problem, trying to find a way to make a piece of code based mouse events working with touch events too. It works fine with the mouse, but reacts weirdly with touch device.

I have to catch a mousedown, or a touchstart, no problem here, it returns the id of the element

```
$('body').on("mousedown touchstart", 'ul#squares li p', function(e){
    console(this.id);
});
```

But when I try catching the fact finger has moved (without going up) over another element, It still returns the id of the element concerned by the touchstart event, as if finger was still on it

```
$('body').on("mouseover touchmove", 'ul#squares li p', function(e){
    console(this.id);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/um3fr0wg/1/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it.

"touchmove" event always returns starting point but finger coordinates are retrievable with event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX or clientY properties. 
Then just need to iterate over my elements and check if coordinates match or not.